# Headless Browser for iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, headless-browser

Basically, what I am trying to do is create an application that goes to a website, logs in, and downloads certain information. I have been told that the most efficient way to do this is to use a "headless web browser," that is a web interface without a front end, such as HTMLUnit. I have not been able to find such a thing for objective-c, however (it is an iOS app). Does anyone know where I might find one?

Thanks,

HBhargava

Comment: NSURLConnection is what you ask for.

Comment: @Till: `NSURLConnection` is no headless browser.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it most certainly is not, but is such beast commonly needed for connecting a website, logging in and downloading stuff? Very rarely, I'ld say - unless of cause there is javascript involved. Hence you are right and my comment was a little too short written in the first place.

Comment: If you don't need JavaScript execution, then you can use any HTTP library, such as Objective-C's `NSURLConnection`, [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), or many other options.  If you need to execute JavaScript and do more complicated things that web browsers do, your options will be much more limited (I don't know any off the top of my head, but that's not to say they don't exist).

Comment: if you need Javascript, run JavascriptCore for headless evaluation.. but its a PITA and doesnt behave like a browser, UIWebView for everything more evolved

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options. If it's using OAuth, or HTTP authentication, and you're just downloading files, you want [`NSURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

However, if JavaScript or web pages that need to be displayed are involved, take a look at [`UIWebView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I don't think this is the correct answer, the question asks for a headless browser. NSURL only performs a HTTP Request (get/post).